# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when we use https:// without www

Tags: asp.net, ssl-certificate

Suppose, https://www.domain.com is my website URL
When I have set redirection from

```
http://domain.com
```

or

```
http://www.domain.com
```

to

```
https://www.domain.com
```

it is working perfect
but when i am opening website with **https://** and without **www** then it is giving 
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.

Any response will be highly appriciable.

Comment: This error message ocurs when a firewall is preventing the communication or the server is configured only to accept certain kinds of connections. Re-configure your IIS check if port 443 is opened or not because your HTTPS request is timing out as there is no listen port to handle the request.

Comment: Have you figured out the problem? ("when i am opening website with https:// and without www then it is giving ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.")

Answer (score 0):

This error (`Error 102`) means `Azure` is not listening on `port 443` or there is a firewall which rejects your connection on the host.

So add `Listen directive` to your configuration:

```
Listen 443
```

Comment: Well , Thanks for response but i have host my website on azure not on apache server

Comment: @NiravPrabtani, this applies for Azure too. Also I edited my answer.

Comment: Ok will try and get back to you